# Is there a default way to get hold of an internal property in jQueryUi widget?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, scope

Im using an existing widget from the jquery-ui labs call selectmenu. It has callback options for the events close and open. The problem is i need in these event to animate a node that is part of the widget but not what its connected to. In order to do this i need access to this node.

for example if i were to actually modify the widget code itself:

```
// ... other methods/properties

"open" : function(event){
    // ... the original logic

    // this is my animation
    $(this.list).slideUp('slow'); 

    // this is the orginal call to _trigger
    this._trigger('open', event, $this._uiHash());
},

// ... other methods/properties
```

However when in the scope of the event handler i attach `this` is the orginal element i called the widget on. I need the widget instance or specifically the widget instance's `list` property.

```
$('select#custom').selectmenu({
    'open': function(){
       // in this scope `this` is an HTMLSelectElement not the ui widget
     }
});
```

Whats the best way to go about getting the `list` property from the widget?

**EDIT**: note i posted my final solution below. However, i dont like having to go back out to the DOM to get the element, so id still be interested to hear the best practices for overriding/extending an existing widget or specific internals.

Comment: is the .list a name of a class?

Comment: No, `list` is a `ul` element that the widget uses to mimic the options dropdown from a standard `select` tag. Also i cannot select this by selector because i might have multiple ones on a page and they wont have id's - only classes.

Comment: have you tried : $(this).find('ul').slideUp('slow') indead of :  $(this.list).slideUp('slow');

Comment: @val: but the `ul` in question is in no way related the select element referred to by `this` thats the problem i need a refernce to list and i cant pull it out of the dom because there is no reliable way.

Comment: @val: actually i take that back... its adding an ID i missed before base on the widget class. i can use a standard selector on that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So in the end it appears that i missed that the list is assing an id based on the name of the plugin and the original element id. so the following works:

```
jQuery(function(){
    jQuery('select#custom').selectmenu({
        width: 100, 
        'style': 'dropdown',
        "open": function(e, data){
            var menu = jQuery('ul#'+$(this).attr('id')+'-menu');
            menu.hide().slideDown('slow');
        },
        "close": function(e, data){
            var menu = $('ul#'+jQuery(this).attr('id')+'-menu');
            menu.addClass('ui-selectmenu-open').slideUp('slow', function(){
                menu.removeClass('ui-selectmenu-open');
            });

        },
        "change": function(){window.location = $(this).val();}
    });
});
```